# Using volumes in Docker to use local files in python script

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to use a volume in Docker to use local files (.mp4) into a containerized python script that process videos. For now the process should be:

1. containerize the python program
2. bind this container to local files so I can use the video in the container
3. process the videos
4. save the result in local files

I haven't found the solution to this problem yet in any tutorial or page, so it would be very helpful if someone could explain how to do it or if there's something wrong about my approach.
Thank you!

Comment: You just mount the local directory to the appropriate location in the container, eg `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path ...`

Comment: If the major goal of your application is to read and write host files, you might find it much easier to run without isolating it in a container.  Use a Python virtual environment to isolate your application dependencies, but not Docker.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1. **Create a Dockerfile for Your Python Application:**

   Start by creating a `Dockerfile` for your Python application. Here's a simple example:

   ```
   # Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
   FROM python:3.8-slim

   # Set the working directory in the container
   WORKDIR /app

   # Copy your Python script and any required files into the container
   COPY your_script.py /app/
   COPY requirements.txt /app/

   # Install any required Python dependencies
   RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

   # Define an entry point (the script to run when the container starts)
   ENTRYPOINT ["python", "your_script.py"]
   ```
2. **Create a Docker Image:**

   Build the Docker image using the `Dockerfile` you created:

   ```bash
   docker build -t my-python-app .
   ```
3. **Run the Docker Container with Volume Binding:**

   You can bind a local directory containing your `.mp4` files to a directory in the container. Let's assume your videos are in a directory called `videos` locally:

   ```bash
   docker run -v /path/to/local/videos:/app/videos my-python-app
   ```

   Replace `/path/to/local/videos` with the actual path to your local video directory. This command runs your Python script inside the container, and it can access the videos located in the `/app/videos` directory.
4. **Inside Your Python Script:**

   In your Python script (`your_script.py`), you can access the video files from the `/app/videos` directory, process them, and save the results back to that directory or any other directory inside the container.

   For example, to access the videos in Python:

   ```py
   import os

   video_dir = '/app/videos'

   for filename in os.listdir(video_dir):
       if filename.endswith('.mp4'):
           video_path = os.path.join(video_dir, filename)
           # Process the video using OpenCV or any other library
           # Save the result back to the same directory or another location in the container
   ```
5. **Retrieve Results:**

   After processing, you can retrieve the results from the container by copying them to your local machine using the `docker cp` command.

   ```bash
   docker cp <container_id>:/app/results /path/to/local/results
   ```

   Replace `<container_id>` with the actual container ID.

By following these steps, you can containerize your Python video processing script and use Docker volumes to bind your local video files into the container for processing and save the results back to your local machine.